# CoordinatorLayout view isn't scrolling with full height header

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using [this](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/) as an example and when I give height "match_parent" to my AppBarLayout it doesn't let me scroll my view.

[image]

Comment: why are you setting it as match_parent?

Comment: Because its my requirement when user enters in to profile screen it should show full profile image thats why

Comment: Can you post  an Image?

Comment: @josedlujan please refer this image